# Callapi and openweathermap

Tags: aiml

I have problem with I think format when I get temperature value. When I call for this parameter I always got it with "d0" f.e. "-0,39d0". How can I fix it? My code:

```
<category>
    <pattern>PADANIE</pattern>
    <template>
      <think>
      <set name="weather_t">
        <callapi>
        <url>http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather</url>
        <method>GET</method>
        <query name="appid"><secret name="openweathermap_secret_appid"/></query>
        <query name="q">zyrardow</query>
        <query name="units">metric</query>
        <query name="lang">pl</query>
        <filter type="jsonpath">$.main.temp</filter>
        </callapi>
      </set>
    </think>
    <get name="weather_t"/>.
  </template>
</category>
```

If I use jsonpath instead filter the result is the same.

```
<category>
    <pattern>PADANIE</pattern>
    <template>
        <think>
            <set var="weather_t">
            <callapi>
                    <url>http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather</url>
                    <method>GET</method>
                    <query name="appid"><secret name="openweathermap_secret_appid"/></query>
                    <query name="q">zyrardow</query>
                    <query name="units">metric</query>
                    <query name="lang">pl</query>
            </callapi>
            </set>
        </think> 
        <jsonpath><path>$.main.temp</path><get var="weather_t"/></jsonpath>
    </template>
</category>
```

[bot answer example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opz66.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the openweathermap API presents the results. The easiest way to get rid of the d0 part is to denormalize the output.

Add this to your denormal substitution file:

```
["0d0", "0"],
["1d0", "1"],
["2d0", "2"],
["3d0", "3"],
["4d0", "4"],
["5d0", "5"],
["6d0", "6"],
["7d0", "7"],
["8d0", "8"],
["9d0", "9"],
```

In your first category, replace:

```
<get name="weather_t"/>
```

with

```
<denormalize><get name="weather_t"/></denormalize>
```

It should now work

[image]